# Is it possible to perform a Sphinx search on one string attribute?

Tags: perl, search, full-text-search, sphinx, perl-module

```
sql_query=SELECT id,headline,summary,body,tags,issues,published_at
FROM sphinx_search
```

I am working on the search feature of my Web site and I am using [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), Perl and [Sphinx::Search](https://metacpan.org/module/JJSCHUTZ/Sphinx-Search-0.27.2/lib/Sphinx/Search.pm). As long as I want to search in all the attributes and I don't restrict it to just one, everything goes well. However when the user searches for a specific tag, I can't just give the result of a fuzzy search, I want to use the power of Sphinx to search only on tags or issues, maybe sometimes the user wants to search on headline and issues.

How can I perform such a task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put it in Extended Match Mode

https://metacpan.org/module/JJSCHUTZ/Sphinx-Search-0.27.2/lib/Sphinx/Search.pm#SetMatchMode

Then you can use Extended Query syntax

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Which includes the field search operator

```
@tags keyword1
```

(Be careful with sphinx, the word "attribute" has a specific meaning - values attached to the document, useful for sorting/grouping/filtering and returning with the resultset. Whereas I think you are talking about fields. All the columns from the sql_query you dont mark as an attribute, are a field - and full text searchable)